# Segmentation Fault: CS50 pset 5 dictionary.c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I'm having some trouble with understanding the problem in my code that caused the segmentation fault. The error message below points to the line: containing `table[tableIndex] = n;`. I have checked that the maximum value of `tableIndex` is lower than the size of `table[]`, therefore eliminating the possibility of accessing an element of an array beyond the size of the array. Please take a look at my code for the load function and I would appreciate it if someone could provide an answer to this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==960==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x403D90
==960==    at 0x401BF7: load (dictionary.c:119)
==960==    by 0x40129E: main (speller.c:40)
```

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 702;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

int wordCount = 0;

bool load(const char *dictionary) {

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }
    
    int wordIndex = 0;
    int tableIndex = 0;
    char tmpW[LENGTH + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= LENGTH; i++) {
        tmpW[i] = 1;
    }
    char c;

    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file)) {
        if (c != '\n') {
            tmpW[wordIndex] = c;
            wordIndex++;
        }
        else if (c == '\n') {
            wordIndex = 0;

            node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (n == NULL) {
                return 1;
            }

            tableIndex = hash(tmpW);
            
            if (tableIndex > test) {
                test = tableIndex;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
                n->word[i] = tmpW[i];
            }

            n->word[LENGTH] = '\0';
            n->next = table[tableIndex];
            table[tableIndex] = n;
            wordCount++;
        }
        else {
            wordCount = 0;
            fclose(file);
            unload();
            return false;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: What is `table`? How is it initialized? What is the value of `tableIndex` when the crash happens?

Comment: You don't check if `fopen` succeeds. This might very well be the source of your problem. But many other things could go wrong in the code you didn't show.

Comment: And why do you use `fread` to read single characters instead of e.g. `fgetc`?

Comment: Also, do you ever treat `tmpW` as a *string*? Because you don't termiante it as such. And why do you initialize all elements to the integer `1` (which is different from the character `'1'`)?

Comment: Quite some undefined symbol in code you provided : table, N, LENGTH, node. Could you show more ? And also the else is never called because c is either != or == \n

Comment: Hi thanks for the responses. I managed to solve the issue!

Comment: What *was* the issue? If you think it might be useful for others then please post an answer to your own question.